# Rename files in subfolders with python and os.walk()

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, os.walk

I want to rename all the files in subfolders of two parent directories replacing spaces with underscores. This is my structure:

```
parent folder
    folder 1
        TIFF
             image 1
             image 2
             [...]
    folder 2
        TIFF
             image 1
             image 2
             [...]
    [...]
```

This is the result I want:

```
parent folder
    folder_1
        TIFF
             image_1
             image_2
             [...]
    folder_2
        TIFF
             image_1
             image_2
             [...]
    [...]
```

This is the script that I'm using and which so far is not doing anything:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os

def replace(parent):
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(parent):

        for i in range(len(folders)):
            os.chdir("TIFF")
            for f in files:
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, f.replace(' ', '_')))
            new_name = folders[i].replace(' ', '_')
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, folders[i]), os.path.join(path, new_name))
            folders[i] = new_name
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Does it do nothing, emit an error, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `os.chdir()` inside `os.walk()` is almost certainly wrong.

Also, take care to not rename parent directories whilst you are traversing their children.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os

def replace(parent):
    remembrance = []
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(parent):
        if os.path.basename(path) == "TIFF":
            for f in files:
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, f.replace(' ', '_')))
        elif "TIFF" in folders:
            remembrance.append((path, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path).replace(" ", "_"))))
    for src, dst in remembrance:
        os.rename(src, dst)
```

Your code never calls `replace()` so perhaps that's the first thing you are missing, though. Declaring a function just tells Python what to do if and when you call that function later on.

If you don't need to recurse really, just do

```py
import os
import glob

def underscorify(path):
    os.rename(path, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path).replace(" ", "_"))    

for file in glob.glob("*/TIFF/*"):
    underscorify(file)
for dirname in glob.glob("*/"):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dirname), "TIFF"):
        underscorify(dirname)
```

Comment: This also doesn't do anything. I'm launching it from the parent folder. Does this code (the first one) go deep down the folder structure?

Comment: That's what `os.walk()` does; it traverses the entire directory tree starting from a specific directory.

Comment: I updated the answer slightly and have provided a demo: https://ideone.com/S8VM4L

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running in the issue where you have renamed a folder, before the `os.walk` has finished walking through it. This can be solved by setting `topdown=False`. Now you will first receive the lowest files, and folders.

Then you can update the files first and then the folders.

```
import os


def rename(path, file):
    old_file = os.path.join(path, file)
    new_file = os.path.join(path, file.replace(' ', '_'))
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)


def replace(parent):
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(parent, topdown=False):
        print(path, folders, files)
        for file in files:
            rename(path, file)
        for folder in folders:
            rename(path, folder)
```

### Edit

The following structure and code was used to test the script:

- Folder structure

```
└───parent
    ├───folder 1
    │   └───TIFF
    │         ├─── file 1.txt
    │         └─── file 2.txt
    ├───folder 2
    │    └───TIFF
    │         ├─── file 1.txt
    │         └─── file 2.txt
    └─── main.py
```

- Code `main.py`

```
import os


def rename(path, file):
    old_file = os.path.join(path, file)
    new_file = os.path.join(path, file.replace(' ', '_'))
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)


def replace(parent):
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(parent, topdown=False):
        print(path, folders, files)
        for file in files:
            rename(path, file)
        for folder in folders:
            rename(path, folder)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    replace(os.path.join(parent, 'parent'))
```

Comment: Thanks. So, I'm launching the script from "parent folder". The script just exists without returning any error nor doing anything. The files are still named as before. Your code doesn't change to the TIFF directory.

Comment: I'll add my testing structure, so you know how I tested it.

Comment: I'm afraid the script is still doing nothing for me. I'm launching it from inside within the 'parent' directory. Just for making sure I added a 'print('hello')' at the top of it and it does print out that.

Comment: If running from within parent (at the same level as the folders), you just use `replace(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.  I just checked and it works for me.

Comment: Why would you use the _script's_ directory as the starting point for directories? Making it traverse the user's current working directory is much more versatile, and less surprising.

Comment: @tripleee, it is only the entry point of my test scenario that was fixed. The code itself can start at any starting point. Which by default is relative to your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

when you using `os.chdir`method,because your working directory is always changing,you should use `os.getcwd` to see the current working directory,you will know what's wrong,and then change the working directory to parent first,then you can change it as you wish.

Comment: Python already knows which directory it's in; you should basically never need `os.getcwd()` unless you need to know the absolute path to the current working directory for some reason.

Comment: I thought the working directory is the where the script runs,but it may not the "parent" directory.